# How to capture key/value inside graph parenthesis with regex in Java?

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I have a string in Java like:

```
 String whatIHaveToMatch = "$item1$={key1=1,key2=2,key3=3,}"+
                           "$item2$={key10=4,key11=5,key3=4,key9=7,}"+
                           "$itemN$={keyi-1=5,keyi=3,}";
```

how can I define a pattern to get every groups each of them contains item and every key/value associated?

**UPDATE:**

I have to build an `HashMap<String,HashMap<String,Integer>>`
in which every entryKey of external HashMap is an identifier of an item, and returns the Map of internal "key"/"value".

The "keys"(in this example: key1,key2,key3...) don't have a specific form, they can be a alphanumerical as it happens.

Comment: What kind of java object do you want to output?

Comment: HashMap<String,HashMap<String,Integer>>

Comment: Could you add the expected output for the input you have given? Also, will your string be always like this ? (all keys beginning with the word "key" and then a number?)

Comment: What did you try so far? Post your code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the job with regular expressions:

```
String string = "$item1$={key1=1,key2=2,key3=3,}"+
                   "$item2$={key10=4,key11=5,key3=4,key9=7,}"+
                   "$itemN$={keyi-1=5,keyi=3,}";
HashMap<String,HashMap<String,Integer>> myMap = new HashMap<String,HashMap<String,Integer>>();
Pattern itemPattern = Pattern.compile("([^\\s{}]+)=\\{([^{}]+)\\}");
Matcher itemMatcher = itemPattern.matcher(string);
while(itemMatcher.find()) {
    HashMap<String,Integer> item = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    String itemName = itemMatcher.group(1);
    String itemContent = itemMatcher.group(2);
    Pattern kvPattern = Pattern.compile("([^=,]+)=([^=,]+)");
    Matcher kvMatcher = kvPattern.matcher(itemContent);
    while(kvMatcher.find()) {
        item.put(kvMatcher.group(1), Integer.parseInt(kvMatcher.group(2)));
    }
    myMap.put(itemName, item);
}
System.out.println(myMap.toString());
```

But be very careful. As kimbert said, regexps are not the right tool for this kind of work.

Comment: You're right! but it works! Yep! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression is the wrong tool for this. You need a simple parser.
If this is the only data format you need to parse then you could write some custom code to parse your string. If you need to parse a range of formats then something like JavaCC or Antlr might be better.